# Consider the set $M=\{a^2+3b^2 | a,b \in N\}$ and $n \in N$ so that $25n \in M$. Prove that $2023n \in M$...

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, square-numbers

**The question**

Consider the set $M=\{a^2+3b^2 | a,b \in N\}$ and $n \in N$ so that $25n \in M$. Prove that $2023n \in M$.

**My idea**

$a^2+3b^2=25n$

By using modular arithmetic( a perfect square can be only 0,1,4 congruent modulo 5 ) we get that a and b have the form 5k. (they both divide 5)

Because $25n \in M$ we can also say that $2025n \in M$ and $2000n \in M$ and $5n\in$.

This means that the problem would be solved if we would show that $2n \in M$ or $23 \in M $

I don't know how to start. I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: That isn’t standard notation for defining a set. I guess you forgot the curly braces. Remember to use \{.\} to show sets.

Comment: the values of $x^2 + 3 y^2$  are all positive integer $n$  such that whenever  a prime $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3$  and $q | n,$  then the exponent is even, also both $x,y$  must be divisible by $q$  with half the previous exponent. That is, if we divide out by $q^2$   until the quotient numer $n / q^{2E}$  is no longer divisible by $q,$  it is still expressible as some $x_0^2 + 3 y_0^2$   This part is just the Legendre symbol

Comment: @WillJagy I don't really understand what you are explaining and also I don't see how is going to help with solving the problem. Can you be more explicit? Thank you so much!

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Prove that if $x,y\in M$ then $xy\in M$. And prove that if $px\in M$ with $p$ prime and $p\equiv2\pmod{3}$, then $x=py$ with $y\in M$.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for your idea, but i still dont get how can I apply this to solve the problem?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Give it some thought.

Comment: @Servaes that p would be 5 and we know that $5n \in M$, which means x=n...

Comment: @IONELABUCIU How do you know that $5n\in M$?

Comment: @Servaes because a and b have the form 5k... correct me if im wrong. Also i tried proving those things and i got to nothing. Can you be more explicit with how i should prove it...? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151393/discussion-between-ionela-buciu-and-servaes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b \in N$ be such that $a^2+3b^2 = 25n$. Note that $a^2+3b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. Since, for any $x$, we have $x^2 \equiv 0, \pm 1 \pmod{5}$, it follows using a case-by-case analysis that $a^2+3b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ implies that $a,b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

So $a,b$ are multiples of $5$, and hence $a^2,b^2$ are multiples of $25$. Dividing the previous equation by $25$ we have $\left(\frac{a}{5}\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac{b}{5}\right)^2 = n$.

Next, we note that \begin{align}
(a^2+3b^2)(c^2+3d^2) &= a^2c^2+3b^2c^2+3a^2d^2+9b^2d^2 \\ &= (a^2c^2+6abcd+9b^2d^2) + 3(b^2c^2-2abcd+a^2d^2) \\ &= (ac+3bd)^2 + 3(bc-ad)^2.
\end{align}

Therefore, to prove that $2023n$ is of the form $x^2+3y^2$ it is sufficient to prove that $2023$ is of that form. However, note that $2023$ can be factorised as $2023 = 289 \times 7$, and $7 = 2^2+3 \times 1^2$. Therefore, $2023 = 34^2 + 3 \times 17^2$, completing the proof.